# How to use a Muse file in electron application

Tags: electron, muse

Hi I have designed a webpage in Muse and I want to make a package output from electron. I have used the quickstart main.js and package.json and my folder structure looks like this

```
----project1
     |
     +--css
         |   
         + ..
     +--js
         |
         + ..
     +-- index.html
     +-- main.js
     +-- package.json
     +--scripts
         |
         + ..
     +-- muse_manifest.xml
     +-- sitemap.xml
```

I am getting this following error

```
Uncaught TypeError: require.undef is not a function
```

Can someone please help me?